# Jquery - Find attributes in Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation (selfmade HTML, no CMS).

Code:

```
<ul id="navmenu" class="open">
        <li><a href="/" class="nav-home"><i class="menu-icon icon-home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="one"><i class="menu-icon icon-one"></i><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="two"><i class="menu-icon icon-two"></i><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="three"><i class="menu-icon icon-three"></i><span>Three</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="four"><i class="menu-icon icon-four"></i><span>Four</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Now I want to realize a "current" state.
Example:
If page "ONE" is loaded, the icon span text should be displayed right besides the Icon (normal state: `display:none;`)
When a Page is loaded the sitename is in the body-tag like:

```
<body class="site one">
```

I need to figure out which site or which class is added in the body tag and display the "state" in the navigation.

Pseudo Code:

```
If "class" is in body >
search for "class" in navigation (search for data-"class" attribute)>
and display span   / set class "active"
```

Can you push me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `[data-filter=one]` to find the matching a-tag:

```
var site = $("body").attr("class").replace("site ", "");

// find any a-tag with attribute data-filter=site, and show any child span-tags
$("#navmenu a[data-filter='" + site + "']").find("span").show();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGNV2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    if ($('body').hasClass('Some Class')) {
           $("#navmenu").css("display", "block");
           $("#navmenu:first-child").addClass("active");
    }
    else {
           //whatever else you care to do
     }

 });
```

Comment: You can also chain the $("#navmenu") commands together, like so: $("#navmenu").show().children("li:first-of-type").addClass("active");

Comment: Honestly there are quite a few ways to do this...the one I wrote in the comment is probably getting closer to it...

Comment: Good way but there are more "classes" than just one. So I would have to code more "if"'s, or?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I need a little more depth, what are the classes your are giving in your bodies, and what are the classes it is trying to find

Comment: I know did something like that to match your code (and from others) to my needs: http://pastebin.com/rccQxZ5m but as I said, now I have to do it for each site.

Comment: I mean, you can always set the body class equal to the class of the li you would like to select, or the data selector, that way you can pass the body class as a variable to select the li on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, accordingly with your pseudo-code:

```
if($('body').attr("class")){
   var classBody = $('body').attr("class");
   var site = classBody.replace("site ", "");

   $("#navmenu li a[data-filter=" + site + "]").find("span").show();
}
```

Comment: Would it be easier, if I add or rename the sites to "site-gome" or "site-blog"? The problem is, there are more classes at the body-tag than just "site".